# C# ArrayList.Add Method Adds Ref to Items?

Tags: c#, arraylist, pass-by-reference

0Suppose I have created an ArrayList and added two strings as such:

```
string item1 = string.Empty;
string item2 = string.Empty;

ArrayList someList = new ArrayList();
someList.Add(item1);
someList.Add(item2);

someFunc(someList);
```

Then I take someList and pass it into a method.  That method performs some manipulation on item1 and item2 and returns, as such:

```
public void someFunc(ArrayList parameters)
{
    parameters[0] = "Monkeys";
    parameters[1] = "More Monkeys";
}
```

I would expect that when someFunc returns that item1 equals "Monkeys" and item2 equals "More Monkeys" as someList contains references to item1 and item2 in indices 0 and 1 respectively.  However, what I am seeing is that item1 equals "Monkeys" and item2 equals "".

Why?  And how would I perform this feat without passing in each item individually by ref?

Comment: "However, what I am seeing is that item1 equals "Monkeys" and item2 equals ""." Are you *sure* that's what you are seeing? Because you shouldn't see that at all. From the given snippets, both would be empty strings.

Comment: The code works for me. Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: @RyanFrame, what is your definition of "works" here? Doesn't throw? Assigns to the arraylist? His definition of "works" is having item1 and item2 reflect "Monkeys" and "More Monkeys". Is that what you see? If so, *how*?

Comment: `item1` and `item2` after your call to `someFunc` should both still be empty strings. Your `someList[0]` and `someList[1]` should be `Monkeys` and `More Monkeys` respectively. If you're seeing anything other than that, then there is something you are not telling us.

Comment: When I test your code, `someList` is changed (both values), `item1` and `item2` not. All as expected.

Comment: After the call to `someFunc`, add `Console.Writeline(someList[0] + " " + someList[1]);` I get `Monkeys More Monkeys'.

Comment: I just tested your code, and somelist showed it had "Monkeys" and "More Monkeys", and both item1 and and item2 show blank strings.  What are you doing in your real code that you aren't showing here?

Comment: I misread the question.

Comment: @MattBurland/@Tory, you are both absolutely right.  I have fallen prey to one of the classic blunders.  Earlier in the real code (not shown) item1 was being set to "Monkeys".  Thanks to all that answered!  This question solicited some solid responses that led to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will simply not do what you expect. Your variables `item1` and `item2` will not be modified by reassigning to the list. You cannot add a *reference to a **variable*** to an `ArrayList` (or preferably a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in the modern .NET world). You can simply add the value itself (which could be a *reference to an **object***). When you overwrite the value that was originally stored in the list, it does not impact the previous variable.

If you need updates inside the list to reflect on outer variables, you may need a different abstraction. You make your variables *properties of a class*, for example, and then maintain a list of that class. And instead of overwriting the contents of your list, you could then mutate the class by changing the property. This technique is demonstrated in [Niyoko Yuliawan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15640949/414076), so I will not redisplay it.

[Another technique mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15640929/414076) is to read the values back into your variables. If the list has the same number of values in the same order, this is doable. However, I should note that if you are adding multiple values to a list, passing them into a method, changing the values in the list, and then rereading those values into your variables, *you probably did not need a list, you needed a class.* If `item1` and `item2` are *really* `firstName` and `lastName`, for example, you don't want `ArrayList list` (or, again, preferably `List<string> list`), you really want `Person person` that has `string FirstName` and `string LastName` properties.

So if you had

```
public void SomeFunc(ArrayList list)
{
     list[0] = "Sam";
     list[1] = "Smith";
}
```

You probably should consider instead defining a class and then working with that class.

```
public class Person 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// elsewhere in your code...

public void SomeFunc(Person person)
{
     person.FirstName = "Sam";
     person.LastName = "Smith";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. However, you can do it like this:

```
class Program
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass a, b;
        a = new SomeClass { Content = "" };
        b = new SomeClass { Content = "" };
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.Add(a);
        al.Add(b);

        SomeFunction(al);

        Console.WriteLine(a.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(b.Content);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void SomeFunction(ArrayList param)
    {
        ((SomeClass)param[0]).Content = "aa";
        ((SomeClass)param[1]).Content = "bb";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get what you wanted, you'd have to read the values back from your `ArrayList`:

```
string item1 = string.Empty;
string item2 = string.Empty;

ArrayList someList = new ArrayList();
someList.Add(item1);
someList.Add(item2);

someFunc(someList);

item1 = (string)someList[0];
item2 = (string)someList[1];
```

BTW, there aren't too many cases where `ArrayList` is a better choice that `List<T>`, in this case, `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this without reading them back from the Array, here is a LinqPad example to show you the output. As you can see the value of the array has changed but your original variables haven`t.

```
    void Main()
{
string item1 = "test1";
string item2 = "test2";

ArrayList someList = new ArrayList();
someList.Add(item1);
someList.Add(item2);

item1.Dump();
item2.Dump();

someFunc(someList);

item1.Dump();
item2.Dump();

someList.Dump();
}

public void someFunc(ArrayList parameters)
{
    parameters[0] = "Monkeys";
    parameters[1] = "More Monkeys";
}
```

using a "true" reference type wrapper works

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public string value;
}

void Main()
{
StringWrapper item1 = new StringWrapper() {value = "test1" };
StringWrapper item2 = new StringWrapper() {value = "test2" };

List<StringWrapper> someList = new List<StringWrapper>();
someList.Add(item1);
someList.Add(item2);

item1.Dump();
item2.Dump();

someFunc(someList);

item1.Dump();
item2.Dump();

someList.Dump();
}

public void someFunc(List<StringWrapper> parameters)
{
    parameters[0].value = "Monkeys";
    parameters[1].value = "More Monkeys";
}
```