# Putting a int variable value which has been calculated by random into an arrayList

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. Is there any way that I can put the `roll1` variable value into the `rolls` arrayList? Do I need to put this section within a method separate to the main?

```
Random diceRoll1 = new Random();

int throw1 = diceRoll1.Next(1, 18);

Random diceRoll2 = new Random();

int throw2 = diceRoll2.Next(1, 12);

Random diceRoll3 = new Random();

int throw3 = diceRoll3.Next(1, 6);

ArrayList rolls = new ArrayList();

int roll1 = Console.WriteLine(throw1 + throw2 + throw3);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Comment: No, because i want to extract to value from the variable

Comment: Then try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640643/c-sharp-arraylist-add-method-adds-ref-to-items

Comment: You don't need to create a new random variable each time, in fact you shouldn't. If the code runs quickly enough, you could get the same "random" number three times, as the random number generator is seeded from the current time. Use a single `Random` and call `Next()` (with your args) on it three times.

Comment: It's also a little unclear what you're asking. Do you  want all three integer values grouped as a single list item? Or do you want them each added as a single list item?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` returns `void`, so this doesn't even compile. Maybe you wanted to do `int roll1 = Throw1 + Throw2 + Throw3; Console.WriteLine(roll1);`?

Comment: @Lauraducky yes i want to put all three integer values into one value then have that go into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you don't need to make a new `Random` each time you want a random number. `Random` is seeded from the current time, so it's very likely that the code would run quickly enough that you get three of the same random number. As for adding the values to a list, there are a few different options for this. If you're always going to put items with three grouped values into the list, you could use a `Tuple<int, int, int>`. Here's an example of that:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int throw1 = rnd.Next(1, 18);
int throw2 = rnd.Next(1, 12);
int throw3 = rnd.Next(1, 6);

List<Tuple<int, int, int>> rolls = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
rolls.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(throw1, throw2, throw3));
```

Or, you could have a nested list of integers, replacing the last two lines with:

```
List<List<int>> rolls = new List<List<int>>();
rolls.Add(new List<int> { throw1, throw2, throw3 });
```

Finally, you could also use an array:

```
List<int[]> rolls = new List<int[]>();
rolls.Add(new int[] { throw1, throw2, throw3 });
```

Another option is to make a custom class which holds your dice roll values (let's call it `MultiDiceRoll`) and have a list of that (i.e. `List<MultiDiceRoll>`).

---

**Edit:**

If you want to use `ArrayList` (I would not advise it, for reasons I'll go into), you can do the following:

```
ArrayList rolls = new ArrayList();
rolls.Add(new int[] { throw1, throw2, throw3 }); // Or whatever other permutation you want
```

The reason I'd advise not doing this is because the items inside an `ArrayList` are `object`s. That is to say, `ArrayList` doesn't use generics the way a `List<T>` does. This means that every time you access an item in the list and you want to use it in some way, you have to cast it to the type you want (e.g. `(int[])rolls[0]`). If you change the type of the list items, you then have a lot of type references you need to clean up and change as well.

Comment: This is great thanks. Could I loop this process to create multiple lists within the main list?

Comment: @RowanReed You can indeed. You don't need to create a new list each time, just store a reference to it and add to it as needed.

Comment: The same goes for the `Random` by the way. You can store a reference to it to avoid recreating it each time.

Comment: What about getting this data back out to display it?

Comment: If you want to display all of the rolls so far, loop through the list and print each one. You could also index into the list to get specific items (e.g. `rolls[rolls.Count - 1]` is the last item added). Take a look at `string.Format()` to look at how to format display strings.

Comment: The question asks about `ArrayList` (for reasons... who knows). This answer does not provide actual answer to the question as asked - consider editing it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the catch. I've edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score -1):

You could initialize a list of type of int and add each element into that list. After adding all elements, you can loop through that list and print it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx